# Dailymotion doesn't work with https

Tags: https, dailymotion-api

HTTPS is unreliable as a `src` for an `<iframe>` tag.

See an example here :
http://codepen.io/okeul/pen/qboMRQ

It's a problem because with [AMP], HTTPS is mandatory with an iframe.

See the issue in AMP Project :
https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/1585

Do you think it's possible to support HTTPS in Dailymotion ?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your feedback Olivier.

We now fully support HTTPS and have a specific `<amp-dailymotion>` component.

See here:
https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/extended/amp-dailymotion.html